# Stub value of Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in Local Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am wondering if there is anyway to stub the value of `Build.Version.SDK_INT`? Suppose I have the following lines in the `ClassUnderTest`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    //do work
}else{
    //do another work
}
```

How can I cover all the code ?

I mean I want to run two tests with different SDK_INT to enter both blocks.

Is it possible in android **local** unit tests using `Mockito`/`PowerMockito`?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Change the value using reflection.

```
 static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    field.set(null, newValue);
 }
```

And then

```
 setFinalStatic(Build.VERSION.class.getField("SDK_INT"), 123);
```

It is tested. Works.

**Update:**
There is a cleaner way to do it.

Create an interface

```
interface BuildVersionProvider {

    fun currentVersion(): Int

}
```

Implement the interface

```
class BuildVersionProviderImpl : BuildVersionProvider {

    override fun currentVersion() = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

}
```

Inject this class as a constructor argument through the interface whenever you want current build version. Then in the tests when creating a SUT (System Under Test) object. You can implement the interface yourself. This way of doing things may be more code but follows the SOLID principles and gives you testable code without messing with reflection and system variables.

Comment: That will not work because getField() expects for variable name and Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is actually a value.

Comment: setFinalStatic(Build.VERSION.class.getField("SDK_INT"), "123");

If this doesn't work maybe PowerMockito over mockito and mock the static field.

Comment: amazing - used similar for Build.VERSION.CODENAME  setFinalStatic(Build.VERSION.class.getField("CODENAME"), "DEBUG");

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Just be sure to reset this value after you are finished testing. I am doing this in the @After method of my unit test so other classes are not affected.

Comment: @toshkinl How did you manage to remove the precompiler error `Call requires Api level 26 (current min is: 24)`? It only vanishes, if I use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` directly. It remains, if I use a wrapper.

Comment: @ASP 
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

There is no Android code that requires any API levels.

Comment: Doesn't work since Java 12

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative to reflection, you can use your own class that checks for API and then use Mockito to test the API-Dependent logic in fast JVM unit tests.

Example class

```
import android.os.Build

class SdkChecker {

    fun deviceIsOreoOrAbove(): Boolean = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O

}
```

---

Example tested method

```
fun createNotificationChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManager) {
    if (sdkChecker.deviceIsOreoOrAbove()) { // This sdkChecker will be mocked
        // If you target Android 8.0 (API level 26) you need a channel
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel()
    }
}
```

---

Example unit tests

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.verify
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.verifyZeroInteractions
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.whenever

@Test
fun createNotificationChannelOnOreoOrAbove() {
    whenever(mockSdkChecker.deviceIsOreoOrAbove()).thenReturn(true)

    testedClass.createNotificationChannel(mockNotificationManager)

    verify(mockNotificationManager).createNotificationChannel()
}

@Test
fun createNotificationChannelBelowOreo() {
    whenever(mockSdkChecker.deviceIsOreoOrAbove()).thenReturn(false)

    testedClass.createNotificationChannel(mockNotificationManager)

    verifyZeroInteractions(mockNotificationManager)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The newest solution with **java 17** *(I guess it helps from java 11 but didn't test it)*

Just follow the steps:

> 1.Add the universal methods to your code

```
fun setStaticFieldViaReflection(field: Field, value: Any) {
    field.isAccessible = true
    getModifiersField().also {
        it.isAccessible = true
        it.set(field, field.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())
    }
    field.set(null, value)
}

fun getModifiersField(): Field {
    return try {
        Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        try {
            val getDeclaredFields0: Method =
                Class::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
                    "getDeclaredFields0",
                    Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType
                )
            getDeclaredFields0.isAccessible = true
            val fields = getDeclaredFields0.invoke(Field::class.java, false) as Array<Field>
            for (field in fields) {
                if ("modifiers" == field.name) {
                    return field
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: ReflectiveOperationException) {
            e.addSuppressed(ex)
        }
        throw e
    }
}
```

> 2.Add these flags to gradle *(it can be changed for other java classes)*

```
android {
    ...

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jvmArgs(
                    "--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED",
                    "--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

> 3.Examples of using

```
//SDK_INT
setStaticFieldViaReflection(Build.VERSION::class.java.getDeclaredField("SDK_INT"), 30)

//SOC_MANUFACTURER
private val testSocManufacturer = "test-soc-manufacturer"
setStaticFieldViaReflection(Build::class.java.getDeclaredField("SOC_MANUFACTURER"), testSocManufacturer)

//SOC_MODEL
private val testSocModel = "test-soc-model"
setStaticFieldViaReflection(Build::class.java.getDeclaredField("SOC_MODEL"), testSocModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sergei for the JDK 17 solution.
A more Kotlin-ish function for Step #1 of [Sergei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76813421/869867):

```
private fun getModifiersField(): Field = try {
    Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
} catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
    try {
        val getDeclaredFields0: Method = Class::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("getDeclaredFields0", Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType)
        getDeclaredFields0.isAccessible = true
        @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
        (getDeclaredFields0.invoke(Field::class.java, false) as Array<Field>).first { it.name == "modifiers" }
    } catch (ex: ReflectiveOperationException) {
        e.addSuppressed(ex)
        throw e
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We recently came across this issue at work. We created a function and in our unit tests we just mocked it. Problem was that we lost the linter and on one release we had an issue that we never caught due to the linter. Anyways, we tried the reflection on JAVA 17 and it worked like a charm, but the moment we started testing all of the unit tests we had so many issues. For example, if 1 unit test that touched the reflection failed for whatever reason (even forcing an exception or Assert.fail("error")) then it caused a lot of random tests to fail. Then we thought, we could deal with that, but then another test was switched over and the reflection caused an issue with another mock and it failed no matter what. So after fighting with chatgpt for hours yesterday and today, we got a nice modified solution that works with the linter. We ended up doing something like this:

```
fun androidSdkVersionAtLeastQ() = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
fun qFun() {
    //api q
} 
    

if (androidSdkVersionGreaterThan(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)) {
    qFun()
}
```

So basically for each API that each part of the code requires you create a function for it and just mock it in your unit test

I hope this helps anybody. the last 2 days were hell, but we had been fighting with this for months, at least a year, on a good solution and now this is just perfect.