# How to mock Build.VERSION.SDK_INT using mockk

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, android-testing, mockk

How can I mock Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in mockk?

I've done the following:

```
@Test
fun testFoo(){
    mockkStatic(Build::class)
    mockkStatic(Build.VERSION::class)
    every {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
    } answers { 22 }
}
```

I end up getting `io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.` once the code hits the `every` block.

Comment: mocking the API level might lead to inaccurate results - compared to emulating it.

Answer (score 10):

You can build a wrapper around the Build config like this

```
object MyAppBuildConfig {
    fun getVersionSDKInt(): Int {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
    }
}
```

Then mock the MyAppBuildConfig with mockkObject and return your desire version number

```
    mockkObject(MyAppBuildConfig)
    every { MyAppBuildConfig.getVersionSDKInt() } returns 22
```

Comment: This is more a workaround than a solution

Answer (score 8):

I ended up modifying `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` using reflection. I added the following helper:

```
private fun setStaticFieldViaReflection(field: Field, value: Any) {
  field.isAccessible = true
  Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers").apply {
    isAccessible = true
    setInt(field, field.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())
  }
  field.set(null, value)
}
```

and then called it like this in my test:

```
setStaticFieldViaReflection(Build.VERSION::class.java.getField("SDK_INT"), 23)
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not seem to work for BuildConfig fields, any idea why?

Comment: I'd guess that the BuildConfig constants are inlined by the compiler because it knows the value at compile time, and that's why it won't work for them.

Comment: On Android use `accessFlags` instead of `modifers`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer in another thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/76813421/916826

1. Need to use a new version of setStaticFieldViaReflection
2. Add a `--add-opens` flags