# How to unit test for different Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking

I have found other similar questions but none of the answers were useful.
In a method I have something similar to:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    // use API available only on Q
} else { ... }
```

When writing the unit test I would like to be able to check all the conditions.

I have found people saying that I should wrap the check `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q` in an object that I can then mock.

If I do that Android Studio shows me a warning because I'm using an API that is for Q+

Other people say that I should use Mockk that allows you to mock static method. The problem is that `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` does not call a method but just a field and I did not find the way to mock it.

Is there a way to do it?

PS
I'm using Kotlin

Comment: Is this Local unit test for JVM?

Comment: @Style-7 I don't know what you mean with `Local` unit test. I'm writing Junit5 unit tests. They are not instrumentation tests so I don't need to access the framework.

Comment: Are you run it by Android Studio or by device

Comment: Sorry @Style-7 but I still don't understand what you mean. I'm running the unit tests sometimes with Android Studio sometimes with gradle directly either on my laptop or on CI. I don't need to have a device to run them because they are just unit tests and not instrumentation tests.

Comment: any closure to this?

Comment: I didn't find anything @HarshVardhan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock Build.VERSION.SDK\_INT using mockk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356739/how-to-mock-build-version-sdk-int-using-mockk)